# Video call got disconnect due to do not keep activities check in android device

Tags: android

ongoing video call got disconnected when it goes to on pause because of do not keep activities checked under developer option in android device how can a user stay in video instead of that option is checked

Comment: Are you initiating video call within the activity? Please show video calling code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check "Is the **do not keep activities** is checked or not" by using below line,

```
int value = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES, 0);
```

If it returns one, create a AlertDialog and ask the user to disable it first, if user clicks on positive button then create an intent for the Settings like below,

```
int value = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES, 0);
if (value == 1)
{
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("You need to disable `do not keep activities` option, press YES")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));

                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: i have implemented that but how skype and all other video call app running fine without showing dialog for these option instead of these option is already checked in

Answer (score 0):

I am entirely not sure if I got you correctly.
But does this: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html
answer your question?

It prevents your app from entering onPause, when a voice-chat is ongoing.